# How to retrieve a variable with coordinates from a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm trying to GET an object with a name and a location property. I need the coordinates of the location property to create a marker at that location. Running this code however results in Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1. I used JSON.stringify(data) in my PUT method.

```js
function getLocation(){
 var name = $("#username").val();
 console.log('getLocation()');
 if(name != ''){
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: '../../' + name,
      async: true,
      success:function(data){
       var oData = JSON.parse(data);
       var marker = new L.marker(oData.location);
    marker.addTo(map);
       $("#username").val('');
      },
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Not found'); }
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: How your data looks like. Add a sample JSON output

Comment: `unexpected token 'o'` usually means you are trying to parse an object and not JSON text, ie `data` has already been parsed from JSON to an object. Check `data` to see if it is already an object: `console.log(data)`

Comment: jQuery.ajax makes a guess on what the datatype is if you do not specify the `dataType` property. You better specify it with value `json`, and then you can be sure jQuery has already parsed the JSON string and passes you an object, not the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be your result is already JSON parsed the

```
  function getLocation(){
    var name = $("#username").val();
    console.log('getLocation()');
    if(name != ''){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  '../../' + name,
          async: true,
          success:function(data){
            var marker = new L.marker(data.location);
          marker.addTo(map);
            $("#username").val('');
          },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Not found'); }
      });
    }
  }
```

or  if you obtain an array

```
  function getLocation(){
    var name = $("#username").val();
    console.log('getLocation()');
    if(name != ''){
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  '../../' + name,
          async: true,
          success:function(data){
            var marker = new L.marker(data[0].location);
          marker.addTo(map);
            $("#username").val('');
          },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert('Not found'); }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[`$.ajax`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with default `dataType` setting will guess the type of response and parse it already:

> **dataType** (default: `Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)`)
>
> The type of data that you're expecting back from the server. If none is specified, jQuery will try to infer it based on the MIME type of the response (an XML MIME type will yield XML, in 1.4 JSON will yield a JavaScript object, in 1.4 script will execute the script, and anything else will be returned as a string).

So as Patrick Evans mentioned, your `data` is already converted to an object, you do not need to use `JSON.parse`.

Comment: better suggestion is to set the datatype to be certain